# How to add legend to seaborn.scatterplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. I'm trying to add a legend (no hue) about sex in a scatterplot of another two factors. I have tried to pass legend parameter to sns.scatterplot() and set manually by ax.legend(handles,labels). However, the first method failed to show up a legend, and the second one raise ValueError.
Here is my current code

```
    bar=sns.barplot(x=df.loc[:,'Sex'],y=df.loc[:,'Salary'],ax=ax[0])
    bar.set(ylim=(10000,30000))
    sca=sns.scatterplot(data=df,x=df.loc[:,'yearsinrank'],y=df.loc[:,'Salary'],ax=ax[1])
    sca.legend(handles=df.loc[:,'Sex'],labels=['male','female'])
    sca.set(ylim=(10000,40000),xlim=(-5,30))
    plt.show()
```

Here is the sample output
[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you use ax.legend or ax[1].legend? To clarify such ambiguities maybe you can add the code (as outcommented lines) in you code.

Comment: @SimonHawe Yeah. But still same ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: But what is the legend supposed to show? Your code generates one type of marker but you have two entries. How does this map? Your sample output also differs from what your code implies.

Comment: @Mr.T I have implemented the first subplot on ax[0]. For the second scatterplot, I have a database with many columns. The scatterplot shows the relationship between salary and years in rank, and the color of points and legend should represents the gender of each point

Comment: So, what exactly was the problem with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70819945/8881141) suggesting the `hue` keyword. Works as expected with a random dataset. I suggest also showing the code that generates two types of markers in the scatter plot. The current code doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by adding a `hue` argument.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16, 5))

bar = sns.barplot(
    x=df.loc[:, 'Sex'],
    y=df.loc[:, 'Salary'],
    ax=ax[0]
)
bar.set(ylim=(10000, 30000))
sca = sns.scatterplot(
    data=df,
    x=df.loc[:, 'yearsinrank'],
    y=df.loc[:, 'Salary'],
    hue=df.loc[:, 'Sex'], # hue argument to specify grouping variable
    ax=ax[1]
)
sca.set(ylim=(10000, 40000), xlim=(-5, 30))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I see. I can do the hue but I can't do the legend

Answer (score 0):

Scatterplot returns an axes object.

Therefore, you can use the fourth way to label an [axes object](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html): label the existing plots (although it is discouraged). You can use:

```
sca.legend(['male','female')
```

or

```
ax[1].legend(['male','female')
```

Comment: I have tried this but the legend shows all points as male, and that's why I pass the handle parameter to ax.legend()

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem by using the hue attribute and legend setter method. (Seems like there is some relationship between hue and legend?)
Here is my current code

```
f,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,sharex=False,sharey=False)
bar=sns.barplot(x=df.loc[:,'Sex'],y=df.loc[:,'Salary'],ax=ax[0])
bar.set(ylim=(10000,30000))
sca=sns.scatterplot(data=df,x=df.loc[:,'yearsinrank'],y=df.loc[:,'Salary'],ax=ax[1],hue=df.loc[:,'Sex'])
sca.legend(loc='lower right')
sca.set(ylim=(10000,40000),xlim=(-5,30))
plt.show()
```

And this is the final result
[image]